# EDITED: If $u_n$ is bounded in $L^2$ and $|F(x, u_n)|\le c_1 +c_2 |u_n|^{p-1}$, does $\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\int_{K}|F(x, u_n)|^2 dx<\infty$ hold?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence, supremum-and-infimum

Let $(u_n)$ be a bounded sequence in $L^2(\mathbb R)$, i.e. there exists $M>0$ such that $||u_n||_{L^2(\mathbb R)}\le M$.

Let $p>2$ and $F:\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that
$$|F(x, u)|\le c_1 +c_2 |u|^{p-1}\quad\mbox{ for a.e. } x\in\mathbb R, \ \forall u\in\mathbb R,$$
for some $c_1, c_2>0$.

Under these assumptions, is it possible to conclude that
$$\sup_{n\in\mathbb N} \int_{\mathbb R}|F(x, u_n)|^2 dx \le M_2,$$
for a constant $M_2>0$?

I'd say yes, as
$$|F(x, u_n)|\le c_1 +c_2 |u_n|^{p-1}$$
and $(u_n)_n$ is bounded, but I am not sure about that.

Anyone could please me in proving (or disproving) that?

$\bf{EDIT:}$ By the answer of @Matt it seems that the statement is false. Anyone could please let me understand if it holds true replacing $\mathbb R$ with any compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb R$?
Namely, if
$$\sup_{n\in\mathbb N} \int_{K}|F(x, u_n)|^2 dx<\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing anything further about $F$ this is in general not possible.

For example let $F(x,u) = 1$ then clearly $|F(x,u)| \leq c_1 + c_2|u|^{p-1}$ with $c_1 = 1$ and any $c_2 > 0$. Therefore this $F$ satisfies the conditions on $F$.

Also let $u_n = 0$ for every $n$ so that the sequence $(u_n)$ satisfies its conditions.

However for every $n$ we have
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} F(x,u_n)^2 dx = \int_\mathbb{R} 1^2 dx = \infty
$$
which shows that there is no finite upper bound.

Comment: Matt Werenski, thank you for your answer. May I ask you, what happens if we replace $\mathbb R$ with any bounded subset of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @C. Bishop The answer is still no since $u_n$ may fail to be in $L^{2(p-1)}$. For instance, take $u_n = x^{-1/4}\chi_{[0,1]}(x)$, then even if $c_1 = 0$ and $c_2=1$, we have $\int F^2 \leq \int |u_n|^{2(p-1)} = \int_0^1 x^{-(p-1)/2} dx$ which diverges for $p\geq 3$.

Comment: @kieransquared, why it diverges for $p\ge 3$?

Comment: @C. Bishop Use the power rule for integration.

Comment: In general, for a compact set $K\subset\mathbb{R}$ containing zero, $\int_K |x|^{-q}dx<\infty$ iff $q<1$.